# Build failures for 'javax.ws.rs.core.Response' dependency

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs

I have a `dependency:tree` as below. And initially, my Eclipse workspace doesn't show any compile time errors.

But when I build my project, I receive both compile time and run time errors saying *The method bufferEntity() is undefined for the type Response*. This is the same for `response.readEntity(String.class)` as well

**A piece of my code**:

```
private myResponse myMethod(javax.ws.rs.core.Response response) {
     response.bufferEntity()
}
```

**My dependency tree**:

```
[INFO] com.esrx.services:pharmacy-resource-center-app:jar:6.31.0

[INFO] +- com.esrx.services:patienteligibility-jaxb:jar:1.13:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.services:patienteligibility-jaxrs-api:jar:1.13:compile

[INFO] | \- com.express-scripts.inf:inf-jersey:jar:1.3:compile

[INFO] | \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.17:compile

[INFO] | \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.17:compile

[INFO] +- com.express-scripts.services:customer-contact-info-jaxrs-api:jar:2.0:compile

[INFO] | \- com.express-scripts.services:customer-contact-info-jaxb:jar:2.0:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.services:benefitprofile-jaxrs-api:jar:1.2:compile

[INFO] | \- com.esrx.services:benefitprofile-jaxb:jar:1.2:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.claims:claims-jaxb:jar:2.0.11:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.claims:claims-jaxrs-api:jar:2.0.11:compile

[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-types:jar:3.1.0:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-validator:jar:5.2.0:compile

[INFO] | +- com.esrx.common:common-exceptions:jar:2.2.0:compile

[INFO] | \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.7:compile

[INFO] | +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile

[INFO] | \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile

[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:5.5.7:compile





[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.14:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.3.14:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.14:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.3.1:compile

[INFO] | \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.13:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-core:jar:14.3.0:compile

[INFO] | +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile

[INFO] | +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.32:compile

[INFO] | \- jakarta.resource:jakarta.resource-api:jar:1.7.4:compile

[INFO] | \- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-types-jaxb-support:jar:3.1.0:compile

[INFO] | +- com.esrx.common:common-types-jaxb:jar:2.2.0:compile

[INFO] | \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile

[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.14:test

[INFO] | \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.14:compile

[INFO] | \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.14:compile

[INFO] +- com.express-scripts.inf:inf-test:jar:3.0:test

[INFO] | +- org.unitils:unitils:jar:2.4:test

[INFO] | | +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:test

[INFO] | | | \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:test

[INFO] | | +- ognl:ognl:jar:2.6.9:test

[INFO] | | \- ant:ant:jar:1.6.5:test

[INFO] | +- com.github.springtestdbunit:spring-test-dbunit:jar:1.2.1:test

[INFO] | +- org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.5.1:test

[INFO] | +- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.6:test

[INFO] | \- com.express-scripts.inf:inf-core:jar:9.0:compile

[INFO] | \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.4.1:compile

[INFO] +- com.carbonfive:test-support:jar:0.9.1:test

[INFO] | +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:test

[INFO] | +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.32:test

[INFO] | \- com.carbonfive:db-support:jar:0.9.6:test

[INFO] +- org.easymock:easymockclassextension:jar:3.2:test

[INFO] | \- org.easymock:easymock:jar:4.3:test

[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test

[INFO] | \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test

[INFO] +- nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:jar:2.2.1:compile

[INFO] +- org.meanbean:meanbean:jar:2.0.3:compile

[INFO] | \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile

[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.7.3:test

[INFO] | \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.7.3:test

[INFO] | +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.7.3:compile

[INFO] | \- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.7.3:compile

[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-easymock:jar:1.7.3:compile

[INFO] | +- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.7.3:compile

[INFO] | \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2.2:compile

[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.6.0.Final:compile

[INFO] | +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile

[INFO] | +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind:jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile

[INFO] | +- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile

[INFO] | +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile

[INFO] | +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile

[INFO] | +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile

[INFO] | +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15:compile

[INFO] | | \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile

[INFO] | +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile

[INFO] | +- javax.json.bind:javax.json.bind-api:jar:1.0:compile

[INFO] | \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-types-jaxrs-support:jar:3.2.0:compile

[INFO] | \- com.esrx.common:common-types-jaxrs:jar:2.2.0:compile

[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:3.0.11.Final:compile

[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.1:compile

[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-multipart-provider:jar:3.0.11.Final:compile

[INFO] | +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:jar:3.0.11.Final:compile

[INFO] | +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.5.0-b01:compile

[INFO] | \- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:jar:0.6:compile

[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile

[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.14:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.14:compile

[INFO] | \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.14:compile

[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.33:test

[INFO] | +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:test

[INFO] | +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.27.0-GA:compile

[INFO] | +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.22:test

[INFO] | +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:test

[INFO] | +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:test

[INFO] | +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.2.3.Final:test

[INFO] | +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile

[INFO] | +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:test

[INFO] | +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:test

[INFO] | +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:test

[INFO] | +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:test

[INFO] | \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.5:compile

[INFO] | +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.5:compile

[INFO] | +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile

[INFO] | \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime

[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:2.5.8:compile

[INFO] | +- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:4.0.4:compile

[INFO] | +- jakarta.websocket:jakarta.websocket-api:jar:1.1.2:compile

[INFO] | +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.56:compile

[INFO] | +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | | \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | | \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:9.2:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:9.2:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:9.2:compile

[INFO] | \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile





[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.5.8:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.5.8:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.5.8:compile



[INFO] | | \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.28:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.8:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.5.8:compile

[INFO] | | \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.12.6:compile

[INFO] | \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.7.7:compile

[INFO] | +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile

[INFO] | \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime

[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.5.8:compile

[INFO] | +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.17.0:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.0:compile

[INFO] | +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.0:compile

[INFO] | +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.17.0:compile

[INFO] | \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.32:compile

[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.14:compile

[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.5.4:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.5.4:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.5.4:compile

[INFO] | \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.14:compile

[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.5.4:compile

[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:3.6.0.Final:compile

[INFO] | +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0:compile

[INFO] | \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.0:compile

[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson-provider:jar:3.6.0.Final:compile

[INFO] | +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile

[INFO] | +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile

[INFO] | +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:compile

[INFO] | \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.13:compile

[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.4.5:compile

[INFO] | +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile

[INFO] | +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.2:compile

[INFO] | +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.4.5:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.5:compile

[INFO] | +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.4.5:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.4.5:compile

[INFO] | | | \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.4.5:compile

[INFO] | +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.4.5:compile

[INFO] | +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.4.5:compile

[INFO] | \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.4.5:compile

[INFO] | \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.4.5:compile

[INFO] | \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.1.1:compile

[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.4.5:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-jetty:jar:2.4.0:compile

[INFO] | \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.44.v20210927:compile

[INFO] +- com.gemstone.gemfire:gemfire:jar:7.0:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-resteasy:jar:3.4.0:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-web:jar:6.4.0:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-session:jar:7.2.0:compile

[INFO] | +- javax.cache:cache-api:jar:1.1.1:compile

[INFO] | +- com.express-scripts.services:session-management-service-client:jar:4.2:compile

[INFO] | +- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile

[INFO] | +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile

[INFO] | \- jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:jar:2.3.3:compile

[INFO] | +- jakarta.xml.soap:jakarta.xml.soap-api:jar:1.4.2:compile

[INFO] | \- jakarta.jws:jakarta.jws-api:jar:2.1.0:runtime

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-spring:jar:7.3.0:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-cxf:jar:5.2.0:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-monitoring:jar:4.3.0:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.5.8:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.5.8:compile

[INFO] | | | +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.12.6:compile

[INFO] | | | \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.12.6:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.14:compile

[INFO] | +- com.esrx.common:common-requesttracking:jar:3.2.0:compile

[INFO] | +- io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-new-relic:jar:1.7.7:compile

[INFO] | +- com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-api:jar:7.4.3:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix:jar:2.2.10.RELEASE:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.5.8:compile

[INFO] | \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-spring-boot:jar:8.8.0:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.8:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:3.0.5:compile

[INFO] | +- com.esrx.common:common-security:jar:12.6.0:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.21:compile

[INFO] | | +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:jar:0.11.2:compile

[INFO] | | +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:jar:0.11.2:runtime

[INFO] | | +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:jar:0.11.2:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.ehcache:ehcache:jar:3.9.9:compile

[INFO] | +- org.jasypt:jasypt-spring31:jar:1.9.3:compile

[INFO] | \- jakarta.jms:jakarta.jms-api:jar:2.0.3:compile

[INFO] +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.18:compile

[INFO] | \- io.github.x-stream:mxparser:jar:1.2.2:compile

[INFO] | \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile

[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.46:compile

[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.7:compile

[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile

[INFO] +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.3:compile

[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.services:usermanagement-cxf-client:jar:7.0:compile

[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.22:compile

[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile

[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.5.8:test

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.5.8:test

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.8:test

[INFO] | +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.5.0:test

[INFO] | | \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:test

[INFO] | | \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:test

[INFO] | +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile

[INFO] | +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.19.0:test

[INFO] | +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test

[INFO] | +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.2:test

[INFO] | | +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.2:test

[INFO] | | | +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test

[INFO] | | | +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test

[INFO] | | | \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.2:test

[INFO] | | +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.7.2:test

[INFO] | | \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.2:test

[INFO] | | \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.2:test

[INFO] | +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.9.0:test

[INFO] | +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test

[INFO] | | \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test

[INFO] | \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.4:test

[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.9.0:test

[INFO] | +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.22:test

[INFO] | \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:compile

[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-inline:jar:3.9.0:test

[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:jar:1.7.3:test

[INFO] | \- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:jar:1.7.3:test

[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.12.6:compile

[INFO] | +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.6:compile

[INFO] | +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.6:compile

[INFO] | +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.6:compile

[INFO] | +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.12.6:compile

[INFO] | +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile

[INFO] | \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.2.4:compile

[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.9.2:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-security-oauth2:jar:2.6.0:compile

[INFO] | +- com.esrx.common:common-security-jwt:jar:4.7.0:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.70:compile

[INFO] | \- com.esrx.common:common-security-token-validator:jar:2.4.0:compile

[INFO] | \- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.18:compile

[INFO] | +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.7:compile



[INFO] | | \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:runtime

[INFO] | \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.services:drugreference-jaxrs-api:jar:2.5:compile

[INFO] | \- com.esrx.services:drugreference-jaxb:jar:2.5:compile

[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar:3.0.6:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:3.0.5:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:3.0.5:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.10.RELEASE:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.70:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk15on:jar:1.70:compile

[INFO] | \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:3.0.6:compile

[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp:jar:3.0.3:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit:jar:3.1.6:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit:jar:3.1.6:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core:jar:3.1.6:compile

[INFO] | | | +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp:jar:5.5.7:compile

[INFO] | | | \- com.rabbitmq:http-client:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:jar:3.1.6:compile

[INFO] | | | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.5.8:compile

[INFO] | | | | \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.0.Final:compile

[INFO] | | | | \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile

[INFO] | | | \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-context:jar:3.1.6:compile

[INFO] | | | +- net.jodah:typetools:jar:0.6.2:compile



[INFO] | | | \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-core:jar:3.1.6:compile

[INFO] | | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:2.5.8:compile

[INFO] | | | \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:2.3.13:compile

[INFO] | | | +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:2.3.13:compile

[INFO] | | | \- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:5.12.0:compile

[INFO] | | \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:jar:5.5.7:compile

[INFO] | \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-bus:jar:3.0.3:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.common:common-config-client:jar:3.4.0:compile

[INFO] | +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:jar:3.0.5:compile

[INFO] | \- com.esrx.core:config-server-shared:jar:0.0.6:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.services:prc-user-profile-jaxrs-api:jar:1.32.0:compile

[INFO] | +- com.express-scripts.inf:inf-types-jaxrs-support:jar:2.0:compile

[INFO] | | +- com.express-scripts.inf:inf-types:jar:2.0:compile

[INFO] | | +- com.express-scripts.inf:inf-types-jaxrs:jar:2.0:compile

[INFO] | | \- com.express-scripts.inf:inf-validator:jar:3.0:compile

[INFO] | \- io.swagger:swagger-core:jar:1.5.4:compile

[INFO] | +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.12.6:compile

[INFO] | | \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.8:compile

[INFO] | \- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.4:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.prc:prc-common:jar:1.16.0:compile

[INFO] | \- com.launchdarkly:launchdarkly-java-server-sdk:jar:5.3.0:compile

[INFO] +- com.esrx.prc:prc-common-test:jar:1.1.0:test

[INFO] +- com.esrx.qwertys:qwertys-common-test:jar:1.7.0:test

[INFO] | \- com.express-scripts.inf:inf-security-jwt:jar:1.3.1:test

[INFO] | +- com.express-scripts.inf:inf-security:jar:8.9.0:test

[INFO] | +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.9.0:test

[INFO] | \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:test

[INFO] +- com.esrx.benefits:accumulator-info-inbound-api:jar:3.0.8:compile

[INFO] | \- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.8:compile

[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-validator-provider-11:jar:3.6.0.Final:compile

[INFO] | \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile

[INFO] \- io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:jar:1.5.0:compile

[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.12.6:compile

[INFO] +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.9:compile

[INFO] | \- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:compile

[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.12.6:compile

[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.12.6:compile
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack traces and the pom.xml file. And whatever information you feel like we would need to _reproduce_ the problem. As it stands, the information you've provided is not enough for us to deduce what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you have a JAXRS 1.X Implemetation in the compile classpath: `budderEntity` is available only since JAXRS 2.0.

The culprit should be `javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile`